# git - multiple JIRA tasks, multiple branches, same file

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, git-branch

I have three jira tasks which is just actually one that was divided into three (Step 1,2,3 for creating a user profile)(not sub-tasks). So I was instructed to create branches for each jira task. My problem is for the second branch I need my codes from the first branch, and the third branch needs my codes from the first and second branch. 
Example:

Branch 1 - created controller.php
Branch 2 - modified controller.php
Branch 3 - modified controller.php
(note that i did not just add new lines in branch 2 and 3, but I also changed some existing ones)

For this to work, what I did was I branched out from the previous one always so that I could get my changes. So branch 2 branched out from branch 1 and branch 3 branched from branch 2.


Should I have just created one branch? Or what would be the best way for me to do this this with git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The PROS and CONS:

- The advantage of having a branch for each set of changes is that you can keep the the changes separate from each other.
- The disadvantage of having a branch for each set of changes is that you must keep them separate from each other.

Let me explain - if you need to keep these changes separate and modular so that you can apply just the changes needed for each JIRA task to something else in the future, or may need to remove just the changes related to a given JIRA task, then branching each one is really nice because you will have a set of visually grouped commits and using a visual git tool it will be easy to see what is going on.  You can also rebase a series of these changes much easier, rather than cherry-picking random commits from a single branch to get exactly the changes you need.

The disadvantage of separating each branch is that you will eventually have to merge the 3 together, and depending on how much you are changing the same lines of code and what the interdependencies are, it's quite possible you will both have conflicts between them that will have to be resolved at merge time (rather than as you develop the changes), and also it's quite possible that you ended up having to make some of the same changes to each of the 3 branches, rather than just reusing the latest changes as you progress through the 3 tasks.

## Git Makes Branching Easy

But, let's be clear that Git makes it super-easy to branch, and there is very little overhead to doing so, and most merges are pretty painless (even when there are conflicts..).  Having 3 separate branches also means you can run testing and CI/CD on all 3 branches in parallel, as needed, and it is very clear to the team if someone else is involved in just one or two of the 3 changesets where and how to add onto your work (say a defect fixed by another team member, etc.).

## Recommendation

All that being said, with the information given, I don't think we can give you an answer on which method is best in your particular situation.  You have to make that call yourself based on the above and similar factors that are specific to your team's product and workflow.

One recommendation I can give - be Agile about this.  Do it the way your team is saying to do it, then find a small case where it doesn't take a lot of time to reimplement the changes, and try putting 2 or 3 tasks together, interspersed into a single branch.  That experience will show you the pros and cons far better than me trying to decide for you without the benefit of all the local factors involved.  Added bonus - if it turns out to be better, you will have a demo of actual work product that you can show to your team as proof - or a demo that you can show and ask their opinions on whether to try it out for the next feature/sprint/etc. or do a bigger demo of that alternate method, etc.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insights and recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion. We want to make things simpler and yet we'll try to satisfy waht your boss is trying to make you do. From what I can see, he/she just wants different branches for different tasks so that he/she can track your work. While possible, I don't think creating three different branches is the best way. What you can do is just create subtasks on your task. You create **1 branch** on the main task. Then on git, make sure your **commit message mentions the subtask**. In your case, you will have three commits. Let's say upon creating the 3 subtasks in Jira you have subtask-001, subtask-002, subtask-003. So in your branch you will have to commit:

```
"subtask-001 created controller.php" - this is one commit
"subtask-002 modified controller.php to blah blah" - and another commit
"subtask-003 modified controller.php agan.." - another one
```

These will all be in the one branch you created and then you can make a pull request for it. In jira, those three commits will appear on **EACH** subtasks long as the subtask id matches what you mentioned in the commit message. It's much simpler and yet you still get to track the revisions in Jira.